# Change text when VisualState is set to "PointerOver",

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am working on `ControlTemplate` for a `Button`.
This is my current code which changes button's color.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1.Styles">

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonBrushAnimation" TargetType="Button">
        <Grid >
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Width="80" Height="30" Text="AAA" />

            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">

                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

                        <!--Take one half second to transition to the PointerOver state.-->
                        <VisualTransition To="PointerOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>

                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBrush" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Red" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="ButtonBrush" Color="Green"/>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I want to change text property of `textBlock` control on `PointerOver` event.
How can I do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames` to your `Storyboard` like this:

```
<Storyboard>
  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Red" />
     <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text">
         <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="BBB"  KeyTime="0:0:0" />
     </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 </Storyboard>
```

You can set a `KeyTime` property value depending on when exactly you need to change the text.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames` does not work in Windows Phone 8.1 Any help?

Comment: @JacekWojcik sorry, I have no experience with WP :(